# Error starting oidentd (FreeBSD8.2)

Tags: freebsd

I'm new to BSD and I have already tried searching on google about this error but no one seems to have encountered it or what.

When I try to run oidentd via "/usr/local/etc/rc.d/oidentd.sh start". It says Command not found.

When I try to run it via "oidentd start" this error is showing: **[line 12] This construct is valid only for user configuration files. Error reading configuration file**

I added my oidentd.conf in /etc/ and already added oidentd_enable="YES" in rc.conf.

Here is what I have on my oidentd.conf

```
default {
        default {
                allow spoof
                deny spoof_all
                deny spoof_privport
                allow random_numeric
                allow numeric
                allow hide
        }
}

global { Reply "hello" }

user root {
        default {
                force reply "UNKNOWN"
        }
}
```

I'm stuck right now and can't find any articles about it.

Answer (score 1):

the "global" directive is specifically defined for user configuration only. that is, it can be used in userhome-hosted oidentd configurations ( ~/.oidentd.conf ). you must remove global directive from /usr/local/etc/oidentd.conf (this is the default location oidentd service will look for oidentd.conf). You can use oidentd_conf rc.conf variable to specify another location for configuration file, so oidentd rc.conf entries may look like:

```
oidentd_enable="YES"
oidentd_conf="/usr/local/etc/oidentd.conf" #the default
```

as for the first error (when starting oidentd as a service) ... this may require a little bit of debugging as I am not sure what may cause this problem. For now, fix your configuration file as described above and try to start the service again.

Comment: if you have your configuration file in /etc/oidentd.conf make sure you specify this with oidentd_conf="/etc/oidentd.conf" in rc.conf service configuration file.